# jQuerys .get() information and gaining a link

Tags: jquery

I am trying to gain the link that is on a certain page of my website per user. I have to use jQuery because I don't have access to the php. I have a script and it does something lol, just not what I want it to do...Any useful tips and support?

```
$.get('/profile?mode=editprofile');
   var a = $('.subtitle a').html();
   $('dl.left a').html(a);
```

Basically the url is `/profile?mode=editprofile` and I want to grab the a href from `.subtitle a` then place it in the `dl.left a` like I said it does something but not sure. I am not getting a console error or anything.

I'm not positive if I am doing something wrong or if I am writing this wrong.

```
<div class="main-head">
  <div class="subtitle">Registration Information - 
   <a href="/u1" target="_blank" style="color:#dedfdf;">View my profile</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I am trying to grab that `/u1` so I can make it work for all pages...The php placeholder the free site gives us will not work on all pages just these pages which are in the profile alone.

Comment: the html doesn't really have a factor here since I know what I am selecting in the selectors, and that it is the a href `.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to retrieve the html from the data returned. Something like this should work.

```
$.get('/profile?mode=editprofile', function(data) {
   var a = $(this).find('.subtitle').html();
   alert(a);
 });
```

Comment: That would be .attr("href") I would think

Comment: Sorry, I thought he was asking how to get the link's HTML so that he can place it inside of another element.

Comment: Um wouldn't .html() present me with the a href still if I did the selector `.subtitle a`

Comment: though anyways I tried .html() came back null, and .attr('href')came back as undefined...

Comment: Please link me to the page so I can see the HTML/Javascript you are working with and I will get it working for you. If you don't want to post the URL for all to see you can message it to me by using my contact form at http://mdl.fm

Comment: I doubt you will be able to see the page anyways since you need to be logged into an account. Would markup would you like? the link is correct and ill update the top with some HTML

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted the HREF - but you want the ANCHOR and .subtitle is the container. Then .html() is correct

Comment: I want the href that is the href `/u1` but anyways I am still getting a null, I believe this may be on my site. it is probably becoming null since it is parsed by php and that is why it is returning null... I have to figure out another way then lol